# How to render content in a custom typo3 grid element ?

Tags: grid, typo3, element, typoscript

I'm trying to make a simple 2 column teaser element that displays an image on the left column, a content element in the right column plus a button link.

This is the original ts, it works but it's ugly and the images are static:

---

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
        29 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
        29 {
        columns {
            20 < .default
            20.outerWrap = <div class="fifty1"><div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left-nowrap"><div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap"><a href="index.php?id={field:flexform_link1}"><img src="{field:flexform_teaserimage1}" alt="" /></a></div></div><div class="fiftycontent"><div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-text"><a href="index.php?id={field:flexform_link1}">|</a></div></div><div class="fiftylink"><a href="index.php?id={field:flexform_link1}"><img src="{$tmplpath}images/button.png" alt="" /></a></div></div>
                    20.insertData = 1 
                }
        }

}
```

---

This is the new ts I'm coding, image & button works but the content element part is not displaying properly:

---

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
        29 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
        29 {
        columns {
            20.prepend = COA
            20.prepend.20 = IMAGE
            20.prepend.20.file.import.field = flexform_teaserimage1
            20.insertData = 1           
                    20.prepend.20.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1
                    20.prepend.20.wrap  = <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left-nowrap"><div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">|</div></div>

                    20.prepend.25 < .default 

                    20.prepend.25.outerWrap = <div class="fiftycontent"><div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-text">|</div></div>
                    20.prepend.25.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1
            20.prepend.30 = IMAGE
            20.prepend.30.file = {$tmplpath}images/button.png
            20.prepend.30.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1
            20.prepend.30.wrap = <div class="fiftylink">|</div> 
            20.prepend.wrap = <div class="fifty1">|</div>

        }
        wrap = <div class="largeteaser">|</div>
        }

}
```

---

Basically all I wanted is for "20.prepend.25 < .default" to work, I tried "< tt_content" or 
"< lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup.columns.default" , the results are sometimes odd and duplicated many content. How do I get the same behavior as adding "< .default" ?

Comment: Do you know the `multicolumn` extension? I like it for being very simple and also user friendly in the backend. I think this may be a solution in your case which would also mean less typoscript for you :-)

Comment: I've heard of it but never really tried it out, we are currently using grid elements since it's very close to templavoila. We can't really switch since the site is already built into it

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution but I made use of prepend/append to sandwich the renderObj

```
        columns {
        20.outerWrap = <div class="fifty1">|</div>
        20.prepend = COA            
                    20.prepend {
                         20 = IMAGE
                         20.file.width = 386
                         20.file.height = 162 
             20.file.import.field = flexform_teaserimage1
                         20.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1
                         20.wrap  = <div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-intext-left-nowrap"><div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">|</div></div>
                    }

                    20.renderObj = COA
                    20.renderObj {
                         25 =< tt_content
                         wrap = <div class="fiftycontent"><div class="csc-textpic csc-textpic-text">|</div></div>
                         25.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1 
                    }

        20.append = COA         
                    20.append {
             30 = IMAGE
             30.file = {$tmplpath}images/button.png
             30.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = flexform_link1
             30.wrap = <div class="fiftylink">|</div> 
                    }

    }
```